# IndentationError : While implement the formula in If..elif statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Experts, I'm new to python. I implement a formula in the if-else statement to get the EPI results. I'll share the formula and the code I tried. Kindly suggest to correct my errors. Note: The Cre value in None Type. Help me to convert it to float/int

My table have the values of (Age,CRE,Gender)

```
Gender[3]  CRE[12]  Age[35]
M          0.7      48
M          0.7      49
F          0.4      57
F          Null     63
```

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=192.168.s.s;Database=Project;uid=AB;pwd=AB")                      
cur1 = conn.cursor()
cur1.execute('select * from total_cohort_Biochemical')

for j in cur1:
    print(j[1]) #tested

type(j[12]) #NoneType
   type(j[35]) #float

    if (j[2]=='F'): #Female
if (j[12] <= 0.7): 
        EPI = 144*(j[12]/0.7)**-0.329 * 0.993**j[35]
    elif (j[12] > 0.7):
                EPI = 144*(j[12]/0.7)**-1.209 * 0.993**j[35]
If (j[2]=='M'): #Male
if (j[12] <= 0.9): 
                EPI = 141*(j[12]/0.9)**-0.411 * 0.993**j[35]
        elif (j[12] > 0.9):
                EPI = 141*(j[12]/0.9)**-1.209 * 0.993**j[35]
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Expected result as

```
EPI: 
111.59414
110.81298
117.26132
NA
```

Comment: `if (j[2]=='F'): #Female` the next line after this should be indented

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Indentation matters in Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. Indentation carries meaning in Python. In particular, each use of `if` should be followed in the following line(s) by an indented block describing what to do if the condition holds. Any `else` or `elif` should be on the same indentation level of the `if` statement.
2. Case matters: it should be `if`, not `If`.
3. Nit: you don't need parentheses following `if`.

This is not the case in your code above - the `elif`, for example, is not at the same level of the `if` statement. Try this

```
for j in cur1:
    print(j[1]) #tested

type(j[12]) #NoneType
type(j[35]) #float

if j[2]=='F': #Female <- Note no parentheses.
    if (j[12] <= 0.7): 
        EPI = 144*(j[12]/0.7)**-0.329 * 0.993**j[35]
    elif (j[12] > 0.7):
        EPI = 144*(j[12]/0.7)**-1.209 * 0.993**j[35]
if (j[2]=='M'): #Male
   if (j[12] <= 0.9): 
       EPI = 141*(j[12]/0.9)**-0.411 * 0.993**j[35]
   elif (j[12] > 0.9):
       EPI = 141*(j[12]/0.9)**-1.209 * 0.993**j[35]
```

Comment: Not just the `elif`, even the two `type(...)` lines above are… off.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, updated. There are other problems too, for example `If` (uppercase).

Comment: Thank you all for your guidance! I have an error again. like TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float' Kindly share a hint to solve the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SathishJay Check for `<=` in the line that's throwing the error. The left side is `None` there.